# First ajax attempt miss authorization in header on iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ajax, ipad, http-headers, authorization

We use windows authentication in our application and it is working fine on our test server. When we publish it onto Production environment (Google compute engine), every first ajax request (per URL) on iPhone/iPad (not matter chrome or safari) after user logon will fail(can not connect to the server). When we perform exactly same action again, it will success. Here is one of our ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GridData")',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        JobName: $("#JobName").val(),
        JobNumber: $("#JobNumber").val(),
    },
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // first attempt in iPad/iPhone(no matter safari or chrome) will go to here
        alert('@Params.AjaxErrorMsg');
    },
    complete: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

After debugging with mac, I found the first ajax call missing the content of Authorization but I have no idea why (this is working fine in any browser with computer version.) Also, I am not sending cross domain request. If I tried to manually put valid data of Authorization for the first ajax call, it will success. Any direction or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For data: why not try `data:$("#your_form_id").serialize(),

Comment: I've tried to do as you suggested, still fail to connect to server when fist attempting.